# DJANGO updating single row result from a template table listing .all() queryset results

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a permissions view with a queryset showing all rows in the permissions db table as a `<table>` in permissions.html template. Looks good :)

I have wrapped a each result as `<form><tr>` with a button in the last `<td>`

My desire is to change some of the fields in a single row and press the button to update that particular permission row in the permissions table.

```py
    def permissions(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    userformset = modelform_factory(User)
    forms_list = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        #     UPDATE RESULT WITH ID OF ROW WHERE BUTTON WAS PRESSED
        #     if form.is_valid():
        #     form.save()
        #         return redirect('permissions') # refresh the page>?
    for user in users:
        forms_list.append({'form': PermissionsForm(instance=user, label_suffix='')})  # REMOVE THE COLON

    context = {
        'forms': forms_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'useradmin/permissions.html', context)
```

Passing a value in the request would mean i would need to have something like str:pk but then that would cause an error as the page will need to keep showing multiple (updated) results.

Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really how django works. You post a form and everything in that form is sent and added/updated. You can use `inlineformsets` to show multiple forms of the same type on the page, but either you submit them all at once or you have some JS/ajax or htmx that will handle just one row, but you'd need a button on each row then, because - as you say, you need the id.

Comment: Yes i was actually looking at FetchAPI to handle a single updation, I was hoping django had a solution directly... I guess indirect will be the way to go.